# how to set the title for spring boot testing method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

in jest, we can set the title or name or description for the specific test. For simple example like below:

```js
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

and the test will give output

```
PASS  ./sum.test.js
✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (5ms)
```

you can find more about jest here: https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started

Then, how to do it in spring? Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming sum method is defined somewhere, here is the code

```
@Test
@DisplayName("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3")
void test() {
    assertEquals(3, sum(1, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using junit framework for writing test cases for spring boot application, @DisplayName annotation is the answer for your use case. It is introduced from version 5 of junit and the below maven dependency is enough to use it in your test cases.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```